# when I set environment NODE_ENV= production it give me development again it doesn't want to change from development to production

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5fh3.png)

when I set environment NODE_ENV= production it give me development again it doesn't want to change from development to production